# Sending the right tag to the add server

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

I am working on a articles based website and some of the content is adult themed. All of the adult themed content is in the adult themed category in wordpress, and all of the normal content is in other categories in wordpress.

their add server is "Google Double Click For Publishers". Is there a way to tell the add server when a page is adult themed or non adult-themed? We do this by assigning labels.

Is there any way to set up the wordpress install so that the articles in the adult themed category send the right tags to the server, and that the non-adult themed category send the right tags to the server?